# Aligning equations in matrix with outside character

Tags: math-mode, formatting, matrices

I would like to align these equations on the equals sign (so that the curly braces are flush) and also align the 'ranges' on the RHS side on the 't'. Can anyone help?

```
\begin{equation}
c(t)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
0 &  0<t<\Delta t \\ 
\alpha e^{-t/T_{1b}} & \Delta t<t<\Delta t + \tau \\ 
0 & t>\Delta t + \tau  
\end{matrix}\right
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\Delta M(t)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
0 &  0<t<\Delta t \\ 
2M_{0B} f(t-\delta t)\alpha e^{-t/T_{1B}} q_p(t)& \Delta t<t<\Delta t + \tau \\ 
2M_{0B}f\tau \alpha e^{-t/T_{1B}} & t>\Delta t + \tau  
\end{matrix}\right
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the `align` environment:

[image]

Aligning the right hand side requires more tweaking by using either a `\makebox` of the appropriate width, and/or using an `\hphantom{}` to insert additional spacing.

If you want the left side to be centered, the replacing the `r`ight with a `c`entered alignment:

```
\newcommand*{\MakeBox}[1]{\makebox[\widthof{\WidestText}][c]{$#1$}}
```

yields:

[image]

### Notes;

- With the `\left\{` you need to have a matching `\right.` (the `.` is needed)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand*{\WidestText}{$2M_{0B} f(t-\delta t)\alpha e^{-t/T_{1B}} q_p(t)$}
\newcommand*{\MakeBox}[1]{\makebox[\widthof{\WidestText}][l]{$#1$}}
\newcommand*{\WideAsDeltaT}[1]{\makebox[\widthof{$\Delta t$}][r]{$#1$}}
\newcommand*{\WideAsDeltaTPlusT}[1]{\makebox[\widthof{$\Delta t + \tau$}][l]{$#1$}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
c(t)&=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\MakeBox{0} &  \WideAsDeltaT{0}<t<\WideAsDeltaTPlusT{\Delta t} \\ 
\MakeBox{\alpha e^{-t/T_{1b}}} & \Delta t<t<\Delta t + \tau \\ 
\MakeBox{0} & \hphantom{\Delta t <{}} t >\Delta t + \tau  
\end{matrix}\right. \\
%
\Delta M(t) &=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\WideAsDeltaT{0} &  \WideAsDeltaT{0}<t< \WideAsDeltaTPlusT{\Delta t} \\ 
2M_{0B} f(t-\delta t)\alpha e^{-t/T_{1B}} q_p(t)& \Delta t<t<\Delta t + \tau \\ 
2M_{0B}f\tau \alpha e^{-t/T_{1B}} & \hphantom{\Delta t <{}}  t>\Delta t + \tau  
\end{matrix}\right.
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The following uses `cases` and some `\phantom`/over`lap`ping in order to achieve the appropriate layout:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  c(t)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
      0 &  0 < t < \Delta t \\ 
      \alpha e^{-t/T_{1b}} & \Delta t < t < \Delta t + \tau \\ 
      0 & t > \Delta t + \tau  
    \end{matrix}\right.
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \Delta M(t)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
      0 & < t < \Delta t \\ 
      2M_{0B} f(t-\delta t)\alpha e^{-t/T_{1B}} q_p(t)& \Delta t < t <\Delta t + \tau \\ 
      2M_{0B}f\tau \alpha e^{-t/T_{1B}} & t > \Delta t + \tau  
    \end{matrix}\right.
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
  c(t) &= \begin{cases}
      \mathrlap{0}\hphantom{2M_{0B} f(t-\delta t)\alpha e^{-t/T_{1B}} q_p(t)} & \hphantom{\Delta t}\mathllap{0} < t < \Delta t \\
      \alpha e^{-t/T_{1b}}                             & \Delta t \leq t < \Delta t + \tau \\ 
      0                                                & \hphantom{\Delta t <{}} t \geq \Delta t + \tau
    \end{cases} \\
  \Delta M(t) &= \begin{cases}
      0                                                & \hphantom{\Delta t}\mathllap{0} < t < \Delta t \\
      2M_{0B} f(t-\delta t)\alpha e^{-t/T_{1B}} q_p(t) & \Delta t \leq t < \Delta t + \tau \\ 
      2M_{0B}f\tau \alpha e^{-t/T_{1B}}                & \hphantom{\Delta t <{}} t \geq \Delta t + \tau
    \end{cases}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) provides the math equivalent to `\llap` and `\rlap` for overlapping content to the `l`eft and/or `r`ight.